# Express Checkout Paypal failure

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have tried to used postman for Express Checkout, but getting following error:

> ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

I read also few other answers but havent found out any solution.
[image]

Comment: I see at least two mistakes in request, but they aren't related to the error message. According to documention (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)  you have to 1) use `L_BILLINGTYPEn` parameter instead of `BILLINGTYP` and 2) use `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT` instead of `AMT`. I have used SOAP format instead NVP but it seems your request to init billing agreement is incorrect. And yes, your method `Sale` is correct.

Comment: Please post your full request (minus credentials)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inputting all the parameter and value under `Headers`.

You should put all the parameters/values under `Params`, located at the right side the URL endpoint field.

See below:
[image]